# Why does inserting a USB device trigger activity on the pins

Tags: gpio, usb

I have this strange phenomenon and unable to wrap my head around it. I have raspberry pi model B (26 pin header). On pin 18 I have a IR Beam Sensor which basically detects a broken beam event. I do this using the following code

```
GPIO.wait_for_edge(4, GPIO.FALLING)
```

This code will sleep till the there is a falling edge on pin 4. It works fine.

Later on I added a usb printer ( a cheap $50 thermal printer) on one of the USB ports (the other port is occupied by a wifi adapter). As soon as i plug it in, pin 18 triggers the above code but since I have a debounce logic after this code, nothing happens and the code continues to sleep.

Turning off the printer has no effect. The only way to get rid of these events is to physically disconnect the usb cable.

So basically I am wondering what is going on? Is it the cheap printer? Can this be fixed in software?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a power dip as the new device is plugged in.  Are any other gpios affected?

Comment: Could be many different things. It would be good to know the circuitry of the IR Sensor and how it is attached to the GPIO pin. Besides joan's suggestion it could also be an induced voltage at the pin during some current spike (EMC), that could be reduced using an RC integrator or by reducing the resistance circuit (high resistance inputs are more prone to pick up erroneous signals). But again depends on the circuit at hand.

Comment: @Joan: Thinking that its the pin, I relocated the sensor to pin 4 and the phenomenon still exists, so its my opinion that it is affecting all the pins (however I did not test on all pins). Also the activity is not only detected on plugging in the printer but during the whole time its plugged in. As soon as I disconnect the printer usb cable, it stops this behaviour.

Comment: @Ghanima: The sensor I am using is this one http://www.amazon.com/URBEST%C2%AESingle-Photoelectric-Detector-Active-Sensor/dp/B00NM1G2TW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1425002095&sr=8-1&keywords=ir+beam+detector

Comment: @Ghanima: Under normal conditions the pin is pulled high using the internal pullup resistor. The pin is pulled low when the relay in the ir beam detector closes. There is a 10k resistor between the pin and gnd when the relay closes. Following your comment should I lower the resistance value? I am not an electronics expert.

Comment: I am not sure either. 10 k is not that high after all. It could be lowered to that extend that the current to the GPIO pin does not exceed safe limits, but I don't expect it to help much.